# Cahephp 3.x : dashed rest api not working

Tags: php, json, api, rest, cakephp

I'm building a **RESTful API System** with **CakePHP 3.1.13** ( i can't use *3.2.x* because the *Server PHP Version is 5.5.x* ).

My controller name is `CmsCouplesController.php` and the url :
 http://localhost/~emanuele/works/grai/html/api/v1/cms-couples.json

works correctly.

BUT the other call ( http://localhost/~emanuele/works/grai/html/api/v1/cms-couples/1.json ) return :

`Action CmsCouplesController::1() could not be found, or is not accessible.`

If i create a controller `CouplesController.php` all works fine.

So why?!

UPDATE : routes configuration

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {


    $routes->prefix('v1',function($routes) {
        $routes->extensions(['json','xml']);
        $routes->resources('Couples');
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });
```

Comment: I follow the Cakephp documentation to configure routes and the two controller are identical except the controller name .

Comment: Please show your routes configuration.

Comment: Obviously the Couples need to be CmsCouples to work with that controller

Comment: @ndm i update the question with the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resource routes require separate inflection configuration

You are missing the proper `inflection` configuration for your resource routes. By default resource routes are using `underscore` inflection, ie currently your resource routes will match `cms_couples`.

Note that you can easily check which/how routes are connected by using the routes shell

```
bin/cake routes
```

It will show you something like

```
| v1:cmscouples:index  | /v1/cms_couples     | {"controller":"CmsCouples","action":"index","_method":"GET","prefix":"v1","plugin":null}          |
| v1:cmscouples:add    | /v1/cms_couples     | {"controller":"CmsCouples","action":"add","_method":"POST","prefix":"v1","plugin":null}           |
| v1:cmscouples:view   | /v1/cms_couples/:id | {"controller":"CmsCouples","action":"view","_method":"GET","prefix":"v1","plugin":null}           |
| v1:cmscouples:edit   | /v1/cms_couples/:id | {"controller":"CmsCouples","action":"edit","_method":["PUT","PATCH"],"prefix":"v1","plugin":null} |
| v1:cmscouples:delete | /v1/cms_couples/:id | {"controller":"CmsCouples","action":"delete","_method":"DELETE","prefix":"v1","plugin":null}      |
```

Long story short, use `dasherize` inflection and you should be good.

```
$routes->resources('CmsCouples', [
    'inflect' => 'dasherize'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Routes Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > URL Inflection for Resource Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#url-inflection-for-resource-routes)**
- **[API > \Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder::resources()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_resources)**

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding...

```
http://localhost/~emanuele/works/grai/html/api/v1/cms-couples.json
```

must be pointing to index function of  `CmsCouplesController.php` controller

then for what reason you want this kind of url

```
 http://localhost/~emanuele/works/grai/html/api/v1/cms-couples/1.json
```

you can give url like

```
http://localhost/~emanuele/works/grai/html/api/v1/cms-couples/json-request
```

then you can put your code in jsonReuest function of the `CmsCouplesController.php` controller ...

If this does not help then explain your question with answer of my question of why you want URl like 1.json

Comment: The url with "1.json" point to CmsCouplesController -> function view($id) .
In documentation it is clear and works with the CouplesController but not with CmsCouplesController.